# Okta spring boot is not working when adding jpa dependency on spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, okta, okta-api

I have these okta dependencies:

> ```
> <dependency>
>           <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
>           <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
>           <version>0.5.0</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
>            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
>            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
>        </dependency>
> ```

When I added jpa in maven

> org.springframework.boot
>               spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

when I'm going to run the spring boot application its giving

> Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'tokenServices'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'resourceServerTokenServices' defined in
>   class path resource
>   [com/okta/spring/oauth/implicit/ResourceServerConfig$LocalTokenValidationConfig.class]:
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not
>   generate CGLIB subclass of class
>   com.okta.spring.oauth.implicit.Non500ErrorDefaultTokenServices: Common
>   causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible
>   class; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot 2.0 as a parent?

Comment: Yes, Im using 2.0.2 release

Answer (score 0):

Im able to solve this issue by token validation to be on the server side instead of the client side
okta.oauth2.localTokenValidation=false